# send array of int in wcf soap postman

Tags: wcf, post, soap, postman

Let's say I have a function that contains List ids argument in WCF SOAP, how can I post an array of ints to that WCF SOAP vis Postman? I swear I've looked everywhere in Google, but there is no documentation about it. Help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"> 
  <s:Body>
    <GetAvailabilities xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <bodyString>leg</bodyString>
      <clinicsxmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
           <a:int>594</a:int>
      </clinics>
    </GetBranchAvailabilities>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

This is the correct way to do it. Since there is no documentation about it whatsoever, i will leave it up there for anyone that needs an example

Answer (score 0):

You want to use postman to test your service, but postman only supports http requests. If you want to send a soap request, you need to edit it in the body, and the sending format needs to be soap-xml. For soap requests, you can use soapUI to test your SOAP service. In short, if your service uses soap binding, you can use soapUI to test your service to send parameters, if you use webhttpbinding, you can use postman to send parameters and call the service.

Answer (score 0):

@Theobald Du: This is what I'm trying to do. I know it is soap-xml, yet i don't know how to send an array of ints through. Here is what I have so far:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"> 
  <s:Body>
    <GetAvailabilities xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <bodyString>leg</bodyString>
      <clinics>
     --> (list of ints to send here. This is where I am stuck)
      </clinics>
    </GetAvailabilities>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```